# Center div with id of a title

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a title and a div horizontally, what I am trying to do is to center the div with the corresponding title.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHVLk.png)

As can be seen in the image, it cannot be centered properly.

This is my code:

```
<h1 id='<?= str_replace(" ", "", $data->title); ?>'><?= $data->title; ?></h1>
<?= $data->text; ?>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="contenido-flex">
    <blockquote>
      <p><?= $data->title; ?></p>
    </blockquote>
    <pre class="is-paddingless" id="a<?= esc($data->id); ?>"><code class="<?= strtolower($data->tip); ?>">
          <?php if ($data->fdc== "JSON") : ?>
          <?= json_decode($data->cod); ?>
          <?php else : ?>
             <?= $data->cod; ?>
          <?php endif; ?>  
          </code></pre>
  </div>
</div>




.flexbox {
    /*  */
    height: 100vh;
}

.contenido-flex {
    margin-top: -700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use align-items: center;
Here is an example:

```css
.flexbox {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.contenido-flex {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='123'>MyTitle</h1>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="contenido-flex">
    <blockquote>
      <p>Title</p>
    </blockquote>
    <pre class="is-paddingless" id="a-11>"><code class="123">
         Some Data
          </code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```